# Access to the static file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel-4
In current project I have single admin page

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return View::make('admin.admin');
})->before('admin.auth');
```

This page has embbed admin.swf file

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/misc/admin/admin.swf">
            <param name="wmode" value="window"/>
            <param name="quality" value="high"/>
            ...
</object>
```

admin.swf file located at /project-root/public/misc/admin/admin.swf

My admin route mysite.com/admin is protected by 'admin.auth' filter.
But everybody can access admin.swf file via URL mysite.com/misc/admin/admin.swf

What is the best way to protect direct access to static admin files by 'admin.auth' filter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afrait it will be very difficult, because it's not Laravel which is giving you access to that particular file, but your webserver (apache, nginx?).

Laravel creates a single page, all other access to files linked in that page are done after that, as requests to webservers, so if you ask nginx for a file and that file exists, it will serve it directly to your browser, otherwise it will redirect the call to your index.php.

You can tell nginx to forbid access to that folder:

```
location ~ /misc/admin/ {
   deny all;
   return 404;
}
```

But then you would have to create a route and a class to serve your files:

```
Route::get('/admin/download/{fileName}', ['as' => 'admin.download', function ($fileName) 
{
    return Response::download($fileName);
}])->before('admin.auth');
```

This `download` method already exists on your Laravel, so, it was not tested, but it should work as is.

Then you just have to reference your files as

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ URL::route('admin.download', ['admin.swf']) }}">
    <param name="wmode" value="window"/>
    <param name="quality" value="high"/>
</object>
```

Note that this is a slow operation, since Laravel will be booted again and again for every single file your page has to download. If you have only one file, it should be fine, but, for instance, a photo gallery, it would take a lot of time to render the full page.

EDIT:

This is the download method declaration:

```
public static function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = array(), $disposition = 'attachment')
```

So if you need to change the headers, you can.

Comment: Tnanks for answer. I tried this approach, but instead of flash movie I see white block. Right mouse click shows flash player context menu "Movie not loaded"
I suppose that Response::download set wrong HTTP headers.

Comment: Edited to show you where to put the correct headers.

Comment: I solved it. :) To set correct header it needs change last parameter from 'attachment' to 'inline'

Answer (score 0):

1.
I placed my admin.swf file to **/project-root/private/admin.swf**
I think this is better than change web server configuration to restrict public access.

2.
I made following route

```
Route::get('/admin.swf', function () {
    $file = dirname(app_path()) . "/private/admin.swf";
    return Response::make(File::get($file), 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash'
    ]);
})->before('admin.auth');
```

Now file can be accessed only after authorization.

**PS** Another variant using Response::download

```
Route::get('/admin.swf', function () {
    $file = dirname(app_path()) . "/private/admin.swf";
    return Response::download($file, '', [], 'inline');
})->before('static.auth');
```